# Run and increment a counter in VHDL

Tags: counter, vhdl, increment

I need to design VHDL to run a counter on a seven segment display. The three inputs are start, stop, and increment based on three pushbuttons. Start will start the counter and it won't stop until the stop button is pressed.  I need to create an increment button which will just add 1 just once. I just need to get the increment button working.

```
process(start, stop, inc, clk)
begin

if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
    if (rst = '1') then 
    run <= '0';
    end if;
     if(start = '1') then
           run <= '1';
     end if;
          if(stop = '1') then
           run <= '0';

     end if;
     end if;


    end process;
```

Comment: http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-33149.html

Answer (score 0):

First synchronise your buttons to the internal clock - pass each one them through a couple of flipflops in sequence.

Then you need to debounce the buttons - one way to do this is only pass on the signal from the input pin once it has been in the same state for a number of clock cycles.  Switches can bounce for a number of milliseconds, so make sure you count for long enough to handle this.

Now you have clean signals to feed to your logic - what you have is a good start, now you need a signal which goes high for a single clock pulse when the `inc` button transitions from '0' to '1'.  This signal can then be ored with your start button to enable the counter for as single tick

For example

```
process(clk)
  variable last_inc := '0';
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    do_increment <= '0';
    if last_inc = '0' and inc = '1' then
        do_increment <= '1';
    end if;
    last_inc := inc;
  end if;
end process;
```